# Security Vulnerability: Web Server Uses Plain-Text Form Based Authentication

Tags: security

I have a server on which apache tomcat 6.0.16 is installed and there are no web applications running.

But I have a axis2.war which is hosting few web services. Now after performing a Qualsys Security vulnerability check it gave me the following result:

Service name: Web server
Vulnerability description: Web Server Uses Plain-Text Form Based Authentication
Severity (scale of 1-5, 5 is highest): 3

I have searched for this error and what I gather is that this error happens for websites which requests web pages from a web server and the form of authentication used is plain text based.
But my doubt is we do not have any web apps on the server running so which authentication it is asking for? 
Or if it is related to axis2.war?

Any suggestions would be of great help.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. so some conf changes are required is it?

Comment: If you don't need this you can disable it I think. Or use SSL or block acces to it on your firewall/load balancer, if you want to use it internally.

Answer (score 3):

Basically is saying that you are transmitting data over an unencrypted port such as port 80. DIsable port 80 and enable on port 443 and should fix your problem.

Answer (score 2):

This means that the Web server allows POST requests via port HTTP/80 (plain-text form based authentication).

Even if your website redirects you to HTTPS, it does not matter, as someone can force the request to HTTP.

For example, someone could save the website locally and submit the forms unencrypted if the website is misconfigured by allowing plain-text POST requests. Or an attacker can create a fake website (clone it, so it looks the same) and redirect login forms via HTTP/80 to the original website, so the user won't notice. Then he may be able to obtain login credentials for other users by sniffing the network traffic.

Here is the example of the regular redirection response:

```
% curl -I http://example.com/
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
```

Here is the example with POST request:

```
% curl -X POST -I http://example.com/
```

or:

```
curl -d'foo=bar' http://example.com/login
```

If your website responds with `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` or similar, then it is recommended to disallow all requests except GET and HEAD on port 80.

Comment: Could please explain how to disallow all requests except GET and HEAD on port 80.